# Read combo selectvalue with Forms.Control

Tags: vb.net

In VB.Net I read my textbox with this line of code:

```
Me.GroupBox1.Controls("textbox" & i).Text
```

But if I want to read a combobox with:

```
Me.GroupBox1.Controls("combobox" & i).SelectedValue
```

I have an error because `SelectedValue` is not a member of `System.Windows.Forms.control`

What can I do to read a combobox dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k6y2h6x.aspx) the control to be a `ComboBox`, you can then read properties as normal:

```
DirectCast(Me.GroupBox1.Controls("combobox" & i), ComboBox).SelectedValue
```